# figure in two column while using a one column environment

Tags: floats, two-column, multicol

I am using one column `book` class and I would like to have just one page in my document consisting of two figures spreading along two columns, as the example in below. I would appreciate if some one give me a straightforward way to do it (if possible)?
PS: I have already tried `multicols` environment and `\twocolumn` command , but were not successful, I image it is because I wanted to use them in a float environment!

part of my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw1.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw1}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw2.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw2}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw3.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw3}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{(a) .., (b) ..., and (c)....}
 \label{pw}
 \end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw11.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw11}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw12.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw12}
 \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{./chapter6/Figures/pw13.pdf}
  \caption{}
  \label{pw13}
 \end{subfigure}
 \caption{(a) .., (b) ..., and (c) ....}
 \label{pw1}
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post working code, not just a fragment. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). P.S. I deleted the `multicolumns` tag, since it's of no use here

Comment: Environment `figure*` is used to make twocolumn figures in two column documents.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the `subcaption` package to set up the `subfigure` environments. If this assumption is correct, you may achieve your embedding your objective by (a) embedding two `minipage` environments inside a `figure` environment and (b) embedding three `subcaption` environments plus a `\caption` statement inside each of the two `minipages`. Note that it's possible to have two logical "figures" inside a `figure` float.

In the following code, the width of the `minipage` environments is set to `0.45\textwidth`, while the widths of the `subfigure` environments and the included graphics is simply set to `\linewidth`. With this setup, no `\centering` instructions are required (or, indeed, be useful). The "1" at the top-right of the following screenshot is the page number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit "demo" option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]  % "[h!]" used just for this example
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth} 
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw1a.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw1a}
 \end{subfigure}

 \bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw1b.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw1b}
 \end{subfigure}

 \bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw1c.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw1c}
 \end{subfigure}

\caption{Three subfigures} \label{fig:3subfigs}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}  %% crucial: no blank lines around this command
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}

 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw2a.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw2a}
 \end{subfigure}

 \bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw2b.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw2b}
 \end{subfigure}

 \bigskip
 \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}  
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pw2c.pdf}
  \caption{} \label{pw2c}
 \end{subfigure}

\caption{Three more subfigures} \label{fig:3moresubfigs}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a column-separating vertical line, like for two-column text?